# Advanced Installer: How to prevent user from installing on unsupport windows version?

Tags: advanced-installer

I'm using Advanced Installer to let users install my game and its associated prerequisites (DirectX, etc).

The game isn't supported on Windows XP- it requires DX10 and Vista+. What's the best way in the installer to let the user know that the game won't work if they try to install on XP?

Ideally the installer would allow me to put up a custom message of some kind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to Launch Conditions page and uncheck from the tree of OS-es all versions that you do not support. This will make the installer present a message to your users when they try to install it on XP.

You can customize this message only in the Enterprise edition, from the Table Editor page, in Launch Conditions table. But the default message is pretty well written, I don't think you'll need to customize it.